# Solving Diophantine Equations Involving Exponentials as Positive Integers

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, diophantine-equations, perfect-powers

Find all positive integers $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $$x^5+4^y=2013^z$$
Now as $$11|2013 \implies 11|4^y+x^5$$ Now by Euclid's Division Lemma we have $y=5q, 5q+1, 5q+2, 5q+3, 5q+4$, so we get $$4^y \equiv 1, 4, 5, -2 or 3 \mod 11$$ and also by Fermat's Little Theorem we have $x^{10} \equiv 1 \mod 11 \implies x^5 \equiv 1, -1 \mod11$, so the only possibility of $11|4^y+x^5$ is when $4^y \equiv 1 \mod11$ and $x^5 \equiv -1 \mod 11$ 
This gives $y=5q$ so our original equation becomes $$x^5+4^{5q}=2013^z \implies (x+4^q)(x^4-x^34^q+x^24^{2q}-4^{3q}x+4^{4q})=2013^z$$, Now as we know that $$(\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}, a+b)=1 or p$$ for an odd prime $p$ so we get $$(x+4^q, x^4-x^34^q+x^24^{2q}-4^{3q}x+4^{4q})=1 or 5$$ but as $5$ does not divide $2013^z$ so there gcd is $1$
So there are six possibilities
$(l) x+4^q=11^z,  x^4-x^34^q+x^24^{2q}-4^{3q}x+4^{4q}=183^z$
$(ll)x+4^q=183^z, x^4-x^34^q+x^24^{2q}-4^{3q}x+4^{4q}=11^z$
$(lll) x+4^q=33^z, x^4-x^34^q+x^24^{2q}-4^{3q}x+4^{4q}=61^z$
$(lV) x+4^q=61^z, x^4-x^34^q+x^24^{2q}-4^{3q}x+4^{4q}=33^z$
$(V) x+4^q=3^z,  x^4-x^34^q+x^24^{2q}-4^{3q}x+4^{4q}= 671^z$
$(Vl) x+4^q= 671^z,x^4-x^34^q+x^24^{2q}-4^{3q}x+4^{4q}=3^z$
Now if $x>4^q \implies x \geq 4^q+1 \implies x-4^q \geq 1$ then we get $$ x^4-x^34^q+x^24^{2q}-4^{3q}x+4^{4q}=x^3(x-4^q)+4^{2q}x(x-4^q)+4^{4q} \geq x^3+4^{2q}x+4^{4q} > x^2+2x4^q+4^2q=(x+4^q)^2$$ and similar is the case of $4^q>x$ so the cases$(ll), (lll), (lV), (Vl)$ are not possible
Now in case $(l)$ we have $$x+4^q=11^z, x^4-x^34^q+x^24^{2q}-4^{3q}x+4^{4q} =183^z$$ so we get $$(x+4^q)^4- (x^4-x^34^q+x^24^{2q}-4^{3q}x+4^{4q})=5x^34^q+5x^24^{2q}+54^{3q}x=11^{4z}-183^z \implies 5|11^{4z}-183^z$$ Now as the last digit of $11^{4z}$ is $1$ and the last digit of $183^z$ can be $3, 9, 7, 1$ and as $5|11^{4z}-183^z$ so the last digit of $183^z$ is $1$ so we get $4|z$ and so $z$ is even so we get $11^z \equiv 1 \mod 3$ also we have $4^q \equiv 1 \mod 3$ so we get $11^z-4^q \equiv 0 \mod 3$ and so $3|11^z-4^q$ but $11^z-4^q=x$ so $3|x$ but from our original equation we have $$x^5+4^y=2013^z$$ Now as $3|2013^z$ also $3|x$ so we get $3|4^y$ a contradiction So we are left with the case $(V)$ which gives $$x+4^q=3^z, x^4-x^34^q+x^2+4^2q-4^3qx+4^4q=671^z$$ but as we know that $(x+4^q)^4>x^4-x^34^q+x^2+4^2q-4^3qx+4^4q$ so case $(V)$ gives $3^{4z}>671^z \implies 3^4>671$ a contradiction So there is one possibility $x=4^q$ which gives $x^5=4^{5q}=4^y$ which implies that $2|2013^z$ again a contradiction. So there do not exists any positive integers $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $$x^5+4^y=2013^z$$
Is My Solution correct?

Comment: Yes, your soluction is correct, it isn't the faster but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your presentation is rather messy but the arguments at their core are correct.

Your proof would be easier to parse (and check!) if you improved its layout;  divide it into a few smaller claims and proofs. For example:

1. **Claim:** If $(x,y,z)$ is a solution then $5\mid y$.

   *Proof.* ...
2. **Claim:** If $(x,y,z)$ is a solution and $y=5q$ then either
   $$x+4^q=11^z\qquad\text{ or }\qquad x+4^q=3^z.$$

   *Proof.* ...
3. Etcetera.

As for details:

1. A lot of exponent are typeset incorrectly; you write thing like $3^4z$ in stead of $3^{4z}$ quite a few times.
2. Roman numerals are I, II, III, IV, V, VI, etc. These are upper case i's, not lowercase l's.
3. You can use the environment `eqnarray` to align several equations, and enumerate them with `tag{}`. For example:
   $$\begin{eqnarray}
   x+4^q&=&11^z,  x^4-x^34^q+x^24^{2q}-4^{3q}x+4^{4q}=183^z\tag{I}\\
   x+4^q&=&183^z, x^4-x^34^q+x^24^{2q}-4^{3q}x+4^{4q}=11^z\tag{II}
   \end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: Is the whole solution correct?